# Uploading a file with Knockout JS, AJAX, REST services and I receive "parseerror" exception from AJAX even if treatment ok

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, rest, knockout.js

I have the following project structure - a .html form where I enter an email address and I select a .csv file for upload (binded with Knockout JS):

```
<form id="importForm" class="form-horizontal">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-3" align="left"><strong>S'il vous pla&icirc;t saisie votre adresse email</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>    
                            <td class="col-md-5" align="left" colspan="2">
                                <div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: demandeImportCollection.demandeImportModel.emailUtilisateur">
                                    <input id="emailUtilisateur" type="text" data-bind="value: demandeImportCollection.demandeImportModel.emailUtilisateur" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse email">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-3" align="left"><strong>Choisissez un fichier</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>    
                            <td class="col-md-6" align="left">
                                <div id="fileUploadDiv" class="form-group" align="left" data-bind="validationElement: demandeImportCollection.demandeImportModel.fileData">
                                         <input id="fileUpload" type="file" 
                                         data-bind="fileInput: demandeImportCollection.demandeImportModel.fileData, 
                                                    customFileInput: {
                                                        buttonClass: 'btn btn-success',
                                                        fileNameClass: 'disabled form-control',
                                                        onClear: demandeImportCollection.demandeImportModel.onClear,
                                                    }" accept=".csv" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-3" align="left">
                                 <button class="btn btn-success btn-responsive" type="button" data-bind="click: demandeImportCollection.demandeImportModel.importer">Importer</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>        
                    </table>
                </form>
```

The javascript model where I treat the action assigned to the button:

```
self.importer = function() {
    if (!ko.validatedObservable(self).isValid()) {
        self.errors.showAllMessages();
    } else if (document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0] === null || document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0] === undefined) {
        AlertHelper.show('<span style="color:#ff5b57;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Erreur</span>', "Un fichier doit &ecirc;tre s&eacute;lelectionn&eacute; pour faire l'import");
    } else {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("fileUpload", document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0]);
        formData.append("emailUtilisateur", document.getElementById("emailUtilisateur").value);
        var url = Global.srv.demandeImport.import;

        if (window.console) {
            console.log("Importer d'un fichier .csv");
        }

        var options = {
                errors : {
                    show : true
                },
                loading : true,
                notify : {
                    show : false
                }
        };


        self.ajaxUpload(url, {
            data : formData,
            success : function(result) {
                if (result.returnCode == Global.CODES.OK) {
                    appModel.goToImportRoute(true);
                }
            }
        }, {
            notify : {
                show : true,
                msg : 'Import du fichier effectu&egrave;'
            }
        });

         // effacer l'information sur l'import anterieur
        document.getElementById("fileUpload").value = "";
        self.emailUtilisateur(null);
        document.getElementById("emailUtilisateur").value = "";
        self.fileData().file(null);

    }

};
```

The AJAX parameters in baseModel.js are set as following:

```
var params = {
                    data : {},
                    dataType : 'multipart/form-data',
                    type : "post",
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                    beforeSend : function() {
                        self.beforeSendHandler(defOpts);
                    },
                    complete : function(serverResp) {
                        self.completeHandlerUpload(serverResp, defOpts);
                    },
                    success : {}, // should be override
                    error : function(jqXHR, exception) {
                        // self.errorSessionExpiredHandler();
                        self.errorGeneralHandler(defOpts);
                        self.ajaxCountError++;

                        // Disconnect User because 3 Ajax errors isn't
                        // normal
                        if (self.ajaxCountError == Global.srv.MaxAjaxErrors) {
                            SessionExpiredViewModel.disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                };
```

And a java REST resource that is configured like this:

```
@POST
@Path("import")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("fileUpload") InputStream fileInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("fileUpload") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader,
        @FormDataParam("emailUtilisateur") String emailUtilisateur){
    LOG.info("--> entree /demande_import/import");

    DemandeImport demandeImport = new DemandeImport();  
    final String userId = getConnectedUser(request, habilitationConfigBean).getUtilisateur().getIdUser();
    String fullFileName = contentDispositionHeader.getFileName();
    int idx = fullFileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    String fileExtension = (idx < 0 ? "" : fullFileName.substring(idx));
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS").format(new Date());

    String filePath = Constantes.CHEMIN_CHARGER + timestamp + fileExtension;
    saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

    demandeImport.setDateImport(new Date());
    demandeImport.setIdUtilisateur(userId);
    demandeImport.setEmailUtilisateur(emailUtilisateur);
    demandeImport.setCheminFichier(filePath);
    demandeImport.setNomOriginalFichier(fullFileName);
    demandeImport.setStatut(0);

    demandeImportService.insertDemandeImport(demandeImport);

    return Response.status(200).entity("File uploaded").build();


}
```

Although the file upload (.csv) and database insert work fine, the AJAX callback treats the treatment as error giving "parseerror" exception.

I tried assigning different values to contentType and dataType AJAX parameters (false / 'multipart/form-data'/ 'application/json'), and I also tried changing the values of REST annotations @Consumes / @Produces : either (MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) / (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8"), but I can't seem to find the right combination in order to avoid the exception.

Any ideas as to what to try next in order to sole this issue?